# AngularJS 5 use in a project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio, nuget

It's been some time since I used `AngularJS` , but when I did use it in a project, it was easy like using `jquery`, I just added a CDN reference to `angularJS` and then I could start and using `angularJS` features in a project.

Now I need to start and use `angularJS 5` version in my `asp.net`, and I see that it has no CDN.

I am wondering what is the difference?

Now I see that i have to use `npm` commands in `CMD` in order to install it.

Isn't their a simpler way? (maybe through visual studio nuget)?

Comment: Simply No! you can't do it using angular 5 but using angularjs you can achieve it as angularjs and Vue js are integratable so you may choose either of them and if I compare Angularjs/Vuejs with asp.net it will be around 10 to 15 times faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't their a simpler way? (maybe through visual studio nuget)?

I am afraid you have to use `npm` `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install the `angularJS 5`. Because we could not get it with NuGet and CDN.

Nuget is now discouraged source for JS packages. You can see a list of all available NuGet package versions on the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/), the most recent version is 1.6.10,  not angular (>2). In addition, Angular 5 has no CDN at this moment.

So, you will have to use `npm` instead of Nuget and CDN to use `angularJS 5` version in the `asp.net`.

Angular cli quick start link: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and the tutorial: [How to Install Angular 5](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/105/How-to-Install-Angular-5-(Tutorial)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i add `Anguar 5` to existing project?

Comment: You can try to use `ng init --source-dir app`. Check the details info from:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/755. If it not helps, you can open a new thread for this issue, it should be a new issue more related to angular.